# Emulating a USB device

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, packet

I have a microsoft xbox one controller. Is there a way I could check the data that the controller sends to windows, and then send it out through a different USB port?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible under condition that:

1. PC has USB device controller with related port
2. You have drivers that will capture traffic from XBox controller, pass it to device port and route all traffic coming to device port to XBox controller (effectively working as USB HUB).